# KeyboardDatePicker grayout days

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So I have this KeyboardDatePicker and I  want to gray out past days and some feature days that. those grayed should not be clickable.

here how my looks now

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                <KeyboardDatePicker
                                    disableToolbar
                                    variant="inline"
                                    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                    margin="normal"
                                    id="date-picker-inline"
                                    label="Select Date"
                                    value={this.state.selectedDate}
                                    onChange={(e) => {this.getTimeSchedule(e); this.handleChangeDate(e)}}
                                    KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                        'aria-label': 'change date',
                                    }}
                                    autoOk={true}
                                />
                            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I read few explanation on the internet on how it can be done here [enter link description here](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker)

it should look like this

```
    renderDay={(day, selectedDate, dayInCurrentMonth, dayComponent) => {
        if (isHoliday) {
           return 'Special component';
        } else {
           return dayComponent;
        }
    }}
```

however I am confused on how to make "Special component"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a custom renderer, you can use the following KeyboardDatePicker props:

- **disablePast** will disable the past dates
- **shouldDisableDate** will allow you to use your own rule to disable dates

In the following example I disable all the past dates (with **disablePast**) and all the sundays (with **shouldDisableDate**):

```
   function disableSundays(date) {
    if (date.getDay() == 0) return true;
  }

  return (
       <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
                disableToolbar
                variant="inline"
                format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                margin="normal"
                id="date-picker-inline"
                label="Select Date"
                value={this.state.selectedDate}
                onChange={(e) => {this.getTimeSchedule(e); this.handleChangeDate(e)}}
                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                    'aria-label': 'change date',
                }}
                autoOk={true}
                disablePast={true}
                shouldDisableDate={disableSundays}
            />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it matched your needs :)

Comment: this looks great disablePast  worked great however I am having issues with shouldDisableDate. I tried to supply a list of days but did not work ```shouldDisableDate={this.state.allTimes}``` I am not sure if I need I need to do it in a specific format

Comment: shouldDisableDate is not an array but a function, executed for each of the dates in order to check if it is valid.
You should check my example of disableSundays to understand how it works.
In you case, your fonction will look for the date in the list of disabled dates: something like:
if (disableDates.includes(date)) return true; (in this example "disableDates" is an array containing the dates you want to exclude)

Comment: I meant can I feed shouldDisableDate? also I was able to get something similar by changing props of those days using renderDay.. now they are grayed out but still clickable

Comment: I mean what I am trying to say disableSundays is a function right? can you add it to the code? I can have a function checking against my list and return true for those days to be disabled but I am not sure what to check against